# MYSQL query for find specific pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, max

[image]i want to fetch Last Conf_type of each bot_no and ord_no given in screenshot

Comment: How you define the last since you do not have a primary key nor a datetime column ?

Comment: it is insert when even new data come. there is no primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
set @type = '';
set @num  = 1;

select BOT_NO, ORD_NO,CONF_TYPE,row_number from (

select
  BOT_NO, ORD_NO,CONF_TYPE,
   @num := if(@type = ORD_NO, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
   @type := ORD_NO as dummy
from t) as tt where row_number=2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT BOT_NO, ORD_NO, MAX(CONF_TYPE) AS CONF_TYPE
FROM BOT_ORDER 
WHERE CONF_DT_TM LIKE "2014-12-02%" 
GROUP BY BOT_NO, ORD_NO
ORDER BY BOT_NO, ORD_NO;
```

Comment: i have added screenshot for output. please check . because i need last conf_type for each BOT_NO and ORD_NO and CONF_TYPE may be max or min so though MAX will no give correct answer

Comment: @Satender346 Add your table structure to understand and where is screenshot